# In twitter future, how to set function of asynchronize return directly

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

I am new to future modern, what I expect from the following code is :
launch future task finished!
end of task

but actualy, the "end of task" appear first.
I want the process in function long_task to run asynchronizely.
what did I missed?

```
import com.twitter.util.Future

object FutureTest extends App{
  def long_task(): Future[_] = { //the function of asynchronize processing
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println("end of task")
    Future.value("")
  }

  val f = long_task()
  println("launch future task finished!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is that `long_task` is a synchronous function that returns a completed future after it has done all the work. A future in and of itself does not start asynchronous work, but is just a handle for notification of asynchronous. It's still up to you to start the work asynchronously.

For your example using a `FutureTask` with a java `ExecutorService` will do the trick:

```
object FutureTest extends App{
  val pool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
  def long_task(): Future[Unit] = {

    // create a FutureTask, which is a Callable wrapped by a Future
    val f = new FutureTask[Unit](new Callable[Unit]() {
      def call(): Unit = {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      println("end of task")
    }})

    // execute the callable
    pool.execute(f)

    // return the uncompleted future
    f
  }

  val f = long_task()
  println("launch future task finished!")
}
```

If you can use the scala `Future` instead of Twitter's the syntax gets a little simpler, since they've abstracted the underlying Threadpool work a bit further:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object FutureTest extends App {

  def long_task() = future {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println("end of task")
  }

  val f = long_task()
  println("launch future task finished!")
  Await.result(f,10.seconds)
}
```

Note the `Await` at the end, which is needed here because with scala's default executorservice, the future work is a daemon thread which will not keep the runtime from quiting as soon as it reaches the last line. `Await` forces the program to block until the future completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way (create the Future first and execute):

```
import com.twitter.util.{Future, FutureTask}

object FutureTest extends App{
  def long_task(): Future[_] = new FutureTask { //the function of asynchronize processing
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println("end of task")
    ""
  }

  val f = long_task()
  println("launch future task finished!")
}
```

Comment: tkx for your ans, but it does not work. I tried to launch 10000 async function, but the println in main thread appear finnaly the same. `object FutureTest extends App{
  def long_task(): Future[_] = Future { //the function of asynchronize processing
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println("end of task")
    ""
  }

  for(i <- 1 to 10000){
    long_task()
  }
  println("launch future task finished!")
}`

Comment: @user3370374 I have updated the answer. It seems twitter has a slightly different API for futures, hopefully this will work better.